# not register ionic application on mobilefirst to use

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

In mobile first tutorial,
one step is `mfpdev app register`

**Question** is what is the use of the registration
as I develop an ionic project and can connect to mobile first without registration  when Cordova web resources Previewed with the Mobile Browser Simulator using MobileFirst command `mfpdev app preview`

mobile first 8
ionic 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @manjunath kallannavar for all the supports

Unrestricted right (without login) to both protected and unprotected resources lead me to confidential client.

As pre https://youtu.be/DlxZYxXszIw?t=15m40s, the author mentions user is as confidential client when using `mfpdev app preview`.
However, this is not documented in IBM reference. (Please quote if you find one)

Also, by using `ionic cordova run android` in emulator, finally challenge received.

Conclusion, with `mfpdev app preview`, user right = confidential client => can access all resources

---

Credit to @manjunath kallannavar

Official explanation:
MobileFirst Development Server includes a confidential client "test" that has an unlimited allowed scope ("*"). By default mfpdev app preview uses this confidential client.

Comment: Glad that you found an answer.Your question did not specify the use of mfpdev app preview.

Comment: MobileFirst Development Server includes a confidential client "test" that has an unlimited allowed scope ("*"). By default mfpdev app preview uses this confidential client.

Link : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/wl_studio_tools/topics/cmbswl.html

Answer (score 1):

`mfpdev app register` command  will register your application with  MobileFirst  Server. Without registering your application with the server, the application on the mobile device will fail to connect to server with an error 'application does not exist'.

If you do not want to use `mfpdev app register` command, you can register your application manually at MFP Operations console.

For more details , refer :  [Registering an application](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/quick-start/cordova/#2-creating-and-registering-an-application)

Update : If you are using command `mfpdev app preview` to preview your web resources with the Mobile Browser Simulator, Security checks are not run on the server-side and security challenges are not sent to the client that runs in Mobile Browser Simulator.

`MobileFirst Development Server includes a confidential client "test" that has an unlimited allowed scope ("*"). By default mfpdev app preview uses this confidential client.`

NOTE : command `mfpdev app preview` is meant for preview the UI , OAuth protocol is not fully supported

For more details, refer :[Previewing Cordova web resources with the Mobile Browser Simulator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/wl_studio_tools/topics/cmbswl.html)

Comment: At first, i thought the same. Connection prerequisite should be registering the app. The situation comes into my developing the app using ionic, without registration(confirmed in web console), i can get data. More strangely, i can directly get other data in scope (should ask for challenge or fail)

Comment: Is it getting data from protected end point  or unprotected end point?

Comment: Unprotected end point can be accessed. The strange thing is that i can access protected end point

Comment: This is unexpected behavior open a case with IBM